# SWIG: python module crashes only when it is deployed to Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, swig

This issue is quite wired and it is driving me crazy. Any help is appreciated!

We have some underlying C codes, which are going to be called by Python modules (Python version 2.6, `Django` framework, version 1.4). We have built Python bindings through `SWIG` 2.0.9. We have used them from the `python manage.py shell` prompt. They are working well.

**If we run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`, everything is still working well. But when we deploy the application as an Apache virtual host, the Python bindings fail suddenly (other webpages without using the C codes are fine). Its url is something like http://hostname.com/basic**. Here is our `conf` file:

```
#Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName hostname.com/basic
  ServerAdmin caisj@example.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  DocumentRoot /home/browser/BASIC/basic

  Alias /static/admin /home/browser/BASIC/_py/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/static/admin
  Alias /static /home/browser/BASIC/basic/static

  WSGIScriptAlias /basic /home/browser/BASIC/basic/basic.wsgi
  ErrorLog /home/browser/BASIC/basic/log/basic.error.log

  <Directory /home/browser/BASIC/basic>
    <Files basic.wsgi>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  CustomLog /home/browser/BASIC/basic/log/basic.access.log combined
```

We need to query the C codes twice. The first one still works and return the correct result. But the second trial just crashes. The code stops and nothing is returned. Some code snippets:

```
from some.basic import rmq       # this is the Python binding created by SWIG
class Maxi:
  @staticmethod
  @contextmanager
  def open(rmqfile):
    driver = None
    try:
      driver = Maxi(rmqfile)
      yield driver
    finally:
      if driver: driver.close()

  def __init__(self, rmqfile):
    with open(rmqfile) as f:
      self.rmqfile = yaml.load(f)
    self.handlers = dict()

  # The rmq.i:
  # int       rmq_query (rmq_track t, unsigned int p, unsigned int q);
  # rmq_track rmq_load (char filename[]);
  def query(self, chrom, start, end):
    h = rmq.rmq_load(self.rmqfile[chrom]))
    rs = rmq.rmq_query(h, start-1, end-1)       # It works and result is correct
    rs = rmq.rmq_query(h, start-1+1, end-1+1)   # !!! Crashes here !!!
    return rs

  def close(self):
      for h in self.handlers.itervalues():
          rmq.rmq_unload(h)

# ==== Django views code ====
driver = Maxi('yaml_config_file_to_load')
result.append(driver.query('chr1', 1, 100000)
```

I guessed it was caused by some file permission problem. But even if I set all Python binding files to be 777, it still fails when working as a Apache virtual host.

I did try to remove the `dirver.close()` statement, still failed. And after code tracing, the `close()` method is never called.

Maybe there is some configuration to cause the python bindings' life cycle not managed properly. But I can not pinpoint the reasons.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

==================

Update:

After reading http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API, I add to my `conf` file:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIPythonHome /home/browser/BASIC/_py
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ......
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess hostname.com/basic processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
  WSGIProcessGroup hostname.com/basic
  ......
</VirtualHost>
```

But it reports error:

```
Premature end of script headers: basic.wsgi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! After searching a lot and trying a lot, I solved this problem. Here is my `conf` file:

```
# Important! My http.conf does not contain this line. So Apache seems to 
#  load the mod_wsgi.so from somewhere else, which is unluckily not compatible 
#  with my C codes.
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
# Place to store file for socket communications. I created the folder manually.
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ......
  # My wsgi configuration file
  WSGIScriptAlias /basic /home/browser/BASIC/basic/basic.wsgi
  # Make the virtual host using only one Python sub interpreter.
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  # Make it run under the daemon mode
  WSGIDaemonProcess hostname.com/basic processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
    python-path=/home/browser/BASIC/_py/lib/python2.6/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup hostname.com/basic
  ......
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But which was the specific change that helped?

Comment: @graham-dumpleton In testing, if I remove `LoadModule`, will report `Premature end of script headers`. If I remove `WSGISocketPrefix`, it reports `Permission denied: Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process`. If I do not use `Daemon mode`, the error keeps the same. If I remove `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`, it is working as well. Actually I need in-depth explanations as well.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for problems with SWIG documented here:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Also make sure you read:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

Comment: Which would generally indicate it is still crashing. Try and use gdb to work out where it is crashing. See http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB